# Getting "The import xx cannot be resolved" while trying to run an existing project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, dependencies

Please bear with my limited experience of working with Java.

I imported the project https://github.com/karantongay/Split-Large-Excel-File-into-smaller-excel-files-using-Apache-POI into eclipse.

On opening the file excelsplitter.java, I see `The import xx cannot be resolved` errors against all of the following -

```
import org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
```

I understand that the dependency jar could not be found. What is the easiest way to get this included and make me run this.
I know how to import an existing Maven project in eclipse but that's where my knowledge is limited upto.

Answer (score 0):

As per the information provided above, one of the ways is to convert the existing project into maven projects which can be done using right click on Project -> convert into Maven project and then you will be having Pom.xml available in your project where you can add on dependencies.

For above issue, apart from maven stuff ,if you are using correct jar may be it’s on in the build path of the project.

Comment: Can't see the "convert into Maven project" in the Project tab.  I am using Eclipse Oxygen.

Answer (score 0):

In your eclipse just right click on Java Project and click Configure and you should see “ Convert to Maven Project ” option.
You should see dialogue like this below. Just add “ Name ” and you should be all set.
Don't forget to add your all custom dependencies in pom.xml file.

Comment: Cannot find that option as well. You may join this chat room https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77499/issues